# Duda con phpMyAdmin Fatal Error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Estaba practicando haciendo páginas web y cuando quería entrar a phpMyAdmin me arroja este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Components\OrderKeyword' not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Statement.php:412 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Statement.php(93): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Statement->parse(Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser), Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\TokensList)) 
#1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Parser.php(499): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Statement->__construct(Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser), Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\TokensList)) 
#2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Parser.php(372): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser->parse() 
#3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Tracker.php(686): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser->__construct('SELECT `SCHEMA_...') 
#4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Tracker.php(829): PhpMyAdmin\Tracker::parseQuery('SELECT `SCHEMA_...') 
#5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php(345): PhpMyAdmin\Tracker::handleQuery('SELECT `SCHEMA_...') 
#6 C: in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Statement.php on line 41
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar a arreglarlo, lo agradecería mucho!

Comment: Diria que tu phpmyadmin está roto. Te tocará reinstalarlo seguramente. No está encontrando archivos de clase por el motivo que sea.

Comment: Renombra la carpeta de phpMyAdmin, descarga otro PHPMyAdmin de la [página oficial](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads) y descomprimes. Renombras la carpeta extraida a phpMyAdmin, creas un `config.inc.php` a partir del *sample* proporcionado, lo editas: `['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` y `['AllowNoPassword'] = false;` y listo.